# What is the average number of tags per question on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange as a whole?

Tags: support, tags

What is the average number of tags per question on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange as a whole?

What is the source?

Comment: There is a minimum of 1 tag per question, and a maximum of 5. I'm guessing the average is between 2 and 3. Is there any reason you need a more specific number, or is it just curiosity?

Answer (score 4):

**Number of Tags Per Question** 
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61442/average-tag-count-per-question 
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61441/how-many-tags-per-question

Answer (score 0):

According to [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/908341/average-of-tags-per-question-networkwide), the average on all Stack Exchange sites is **2.85**.

If we [exclude meta sites](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/908344/average-of-tags-per-question-networkwide-metas-excluded), the result is **2.86**, probably because meta sites have much fewer questions than main sites.