# How is it possible for a question to have more than 5 tags?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

[Robert Harvey's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126426/179419) to [What is the average number of tags per question on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange as a whole?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126418/what-is-the-average-number-of-tags-per-question-in-stack-overflow-and-stack-exch) inspired me to go looking. On SO there are 24 questions with more than 5 tags spread out from 2008 to mid January 2011, see [this data query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/64634/questions-with-more-than-5-tags).

I couldn't be bothered to check every site but went through about 10. The only other example I found is here, [this question actually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111823/do-i-have-to-use-gravatar-to-change-my-picture-on-this-site), which is from November 2011.

How is this possible? Is it still possible?

P.S. I'm not asking whether it'd be a good thing.

and I couldn't replicate it when creating this question.

Comment: It looks like those were created by some problem with the Edit Tags ability on SO. Weird.

Comment: @sixlettervariables, I only noticed on 2 but you're right they all seem to have been edited to have 6, which I also can't replicate.

Comment: I just tried it on here. It didn't work, but that might be because I was using synonyms so that there wouldn't be a bunch of useless tags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We didn't constrain the number of tags in the beginning, so a few are from that wild time; the others are just bugs that crept in.

I'm retagging all of them now.